# fee of smart contract deploying as transfer channel

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, contract-invocation, fees

I want to deploy a smart contract for deposit part of an exchange...I know the creator of a smart contract should pay fee(gas fee) to deploy it...my question is as follows: do senders also should pay fee for every transaction that send to contract or it is free for them?

Answer (score 0):

The person who sends the transaction to the contract will pay the fee for that transaction.

Comment: Can you please link the website?

Comment: you right... I misunderstand about it.